# jquery mobile transition event issues

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am creating a jquery mobile site. I am using the latest version of jQ mobile.
I have a button on the top bar which opens a menu. The button is available on the homepage only. On other pages a back button takes its place. The menu div is under the page div (think Facebook iphone app).

When I transition to a page without a lot of content, the menu shows under the div of the new page. I went through the jQ mobile docs and found several events that seemed to fit the bill. To the homepage I added this JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function(){
    $('#menu').show();
  });
  $(document).on("pagebeforehide", function() {
    $('#menu').hide();
  });
</script>
```

I was expecting that `beforepagehide` will fire before the transition and hide the menu div and that `pagebeforeshow` would show it again coming back. This is not working.
Am I choosing the wrong events? Am I missing something completely about how jQ mobile works?

**Edit:** I tried modifiying the code like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("pageinit", function(){
      $('div[data-role="page"]').one("pagebeforeshow", function(event, ui){
          alert("show");
          $('#menu').show();
      });
      $('div[data-role="page"]').one("pagebeforehide", function(event, ui) {
          alert("hide");
          $('#menu').hide();
      });
   });
</script>
```

I was expecting the above code to bind the event for one execution each time the page is displayed. What I am getting is the "hide" alert twice and then the "show" alert before the page I am transitioning to shows. I have a feeling I'm missing something in the jQuery mobile life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

I made an working example for you: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PGxuR/)**

Unlike your example I made a simple div that shows every time during page transitions. You can test it by removing javascript code.

This is js code that hides/shows the custom div:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforehide','[data-role="page"]',function(e,data){    
    $('#test-div').hide();  
});

$(document).on('pageshow','[data-role="page"]',function(e,data){    
    $('#test-div').show();  
});
```

There are 3 more events before **[pagebeforehide](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforehide/)**. We cant's use them because they would trigger only once before page is loaded into the DOM. First event to trigger every time is **[pagebeforehide](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforehide/)** and last event to trigger every time is **[pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)**.

One more thing not related to this problem, this syntax will not work:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(){
  $('div[data-role="page"]').one("pagebeforeshow", function(event, ui){
      alert("show");
      $('#menu').show();
  });
  $('div[data-role="page"]').one("pagebeforehide", function(event, ui) {
      alert("hide");
      $('#menu').hide();
  });
});
```

page events can't be serialized like that. Page event can't be a child of another page event.

### More information

If you want to find more about this and how page events work then take a loon an **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)** in my **personal blog**.

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this, but I do have a page event inside a page event. I don't understand why you thing this doesn't work.